# Refresh Capybara's session DOM contents

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am trying to parse a website using Selenium/Capybara. Right now it looks like this:

```
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)

session.visit "https://somesite.com/page1"

element = session.all( :css, '.table .row a' ).each do |el|
  el.click

  # get some element's data

  session.evaluate_script('window.history.back()')
end

# repeat
```

Problem is, when I'm trying to get the data from the second page I am on, Capybara tells me that `Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.` which absolutely makes sense, however I'm struggling to find a way to create a new DOM variable and parse it in the documentation.

Same thing happens if  I navigate back trying to repeat the actions and click on the second link in a row. I assume I need to re-create the session or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work like you're trying you're going to need to keep a counter and find the elements each time through your loop - something along the lines of

```
counter = 0
while (el = session.all( :css, '.table .row a', minimum: 1 )[counter]) do
  el.click

  # get some element's data

  counter += 1
  session.go_back
end
```

or if the links are just standard you could gather the hrefs and then just visit them

```
element = session.all( :css, '.table .row a', minimum:1 ).map {|a| a['href']} do |url|
  session.visit(url)

  # get some element's data

end
```

Comment: thank you for this great answer. I am going with the second example - I think it saves some time if switching  between pages directly. Any advice on how to switch between the top level paginated pages when the HREFs from one page are finished?